# Convert pointer to 2D char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

This probably has been asked already, but I'm unable to find anything on it.

I have a string array, where the numbers of strings in it is determined at runtime (the max string length is known, if that helps). Since I need global access to that array, I used a pointer and malloc'ed enough space to it when I actually know how much has to fit in there:

```
char *global_strings;

void some_func(int strings_nr, int strings_size)
{
    global_strings = (char*) malloc(strings_nr* strings_size* sizeof(char));
}
```

What would be the correct way in C to use this pointer like a two-dimensional char array equivalent to
`global_strings[strings_nr][strings_size]` ?

Comment: to use it as a 2D array, you must calculate each string start yourself using `global_strings[i*string_size]` for string `i` where you can store a string of max `string_size` chars including the terminating null.

Comment: "*I have a string array*" where?

Comment: Also, there is absolutely no need to cast `malloc()` & friends in C.

Comment: Then I'd be interested in your malloc-free suggestion.

Comment: by definition *sizeof(char)* is 1, it is useless to multiply by 1

Comment: That's true, just a habit of mine to keep things consistent with other data types. :)

Comment: as said by Paul if you want to not always access char in your array but to also get a sub string through *global_strings[index]* you need to reserve the place for the null characters ending each sub-string. If *strings_size* also count the null char that is ok, else you need _malloc(strings_nr* (strings_size + 1))_. May be also force the presence of the null char at index 0 of each sub-string to make them empty just after the *malloc* (or directely use *calloc*) ?

Comment: You really need to save *strings_nr* and *strings_size*, without them your array is unusable, what about a *struct* to save them more the allocated block ?

Answer (score 1):

As a global pointer to 2D data, whose N*M characteristics defined at run-time, I'd recommend a helper function to access the strings rather than directly use it.  Make it `inline` or as a macro if desired.

```
char *global_strings = NULL;
size_t global_strings_nr = 0;
size_t global_strings_size = 0;

// Allocation -  
// OK to call again, but prior data may not be organized well with a new string_size
// More code needed to handle that.
void some_func(int strings_nr, int strings_size) {
  global_strings_nr = strings_nr;      // save for later use
  global_strings_size = strings_size;  // save for later use
  global_strings = realloc(global_strings,
      sizeof *global_strings * strings_nr * strings_size);
  if (global_strings == NULL) {
    global_strings_nr = global_strings_size = 0;
  }
}

// Access function
char *global_strings_get(size_t index)  {
  if (index >= global_strings_nr) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return global_strings + index*global_strings_size;
}

#define GLOBAL_STRINGS_GET_WO_CHECK(index) \
   (global_strings + (index)*global_strings_size)
```

---

Better to use `size_t` for array indexing and sizing than `int`.

Casts not needed.

Memory calculations should begin with a `size_t` rather than `int * int * size_t`.

Comment: As I said in a remark of the question better to use a *struct* grouping the 2 size and the pointer, that allows to have any number of these 2D arrays without having to multiply the global (dirty) variables, and to give the *struct* to any functions rather than 3 params hoping them consistent, or to have to multiply the *global_nn_strings_get* definitions

Comment: @bruno Perhaps.  I like the `struct` part.  Concerning global: if it is _better_ depends on the application.  Such abstraction is usually better, yet, for example, with life critical apps, better to allocate all needs at start-up rather than risk a out-of-memory error later - half-way through the operation.  The advice is good, yet not a truism and a scope creep on OP's post.